# How to search for the value of an object in a json file?

Tags: c++, json, parsing, search

I'm trying to search for the value of an object in my json file.

If my json file is this:

```
[
 {
  "friendName": "Ann",
  "birthday": "1990-04-19",
  "favoriteColor": "Purple",
 },
 {
  "friendName": "Max",
  "birthday": "1993-10-07",
  "favoriteColor": "Purple",
 },
 {
  "friendName": "Bob",
  "birthday": "1992-02-20",
  "favoriteColor": "Red",
 }
]
```

How would I be able to do something like (in pseudo):

```
if (object value is "Purple") {
    print object value of friendName;
}
```

So that the end result would be

```
Ann
Max
```

I am using the json parser Json for Modern C++ (https://github.com/nlohmann/json). I'm new to C++ so I'm having difficulty understanding the README. I'm using Xcode (version 6.4)

I've tried using this:

```
// find an entry
if (o.find("foo") != o.end()) {
// there is an entry with key "foo"
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I know how to print the value of an object if I know its positon using this code:

```
std::cout << obj[0]["friendName"];
```

Which would result in:

```
Ann
```

Also, I'm also looking for a way to read the first part of a value. For example, if I wanted to list the names of people whose birthdays are during or after the year 1992, it would print:

```
Max
Bob
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the magic of C++11 (and a very well-designed library), the answer is almost identical to your pseudo-code:

```
for (const auto& obj : my_json) {
    if (obj["favoriteColor"] == "Purple") {
        std::cout << obj["friendName"] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

prints

```
"Ann"
"Max"
```